# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, adminform

I´ve install correctly the package `Magento-CE-2.1.2_sample_data-2016-10-11-11-24-30`.

I can see the test page `LUMA` perfectly. But when I try to enter on the admin page, I put the correct user and password and the message shows:

> There has been an error processing your request Notice: Use of
>   undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS' in
>   /home/storage/4/28/79/a7consulting2/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 73

I've installed the magento on the 'store' folder...

Could you help me?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1766822/2047249

Answer (score 6):

You  need  to install php curl (apt-get install php5-curl or 
apt-get install php7.0-curl if you useung php7 )
and restart your web server for apache is service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your php version is messed up: your cli version and apache version (info.php output) could be different.

In my case: cli 7.1 vs php.info 7.0, and because my php curl extension is installed as version php7.1, I got the same error in a fresh Magento 2.2.6 installation. Disable 7.0 and enable 7.1 will fix the issue, assume that you also have php7.1-curl installed.

[This doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) tells you all the required php extensions as a system requirement, IMO for Magento 2.2.* use php7.1 encounters less issues than php7.0.